# Chromedriver failed to start

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, robotframework

I'm working with the most recent version of Chromedriver, but it seems to be failing to start. When I try to start tests with it, it simply loads to a blank screen with "data;," in the address bar, and prints this in the debug console:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome 109.0.5414
Driver [C:\Users\Peter.[redacted]\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\109.0.5414\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
[ FAIL ] WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

[ FAIL ] AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I have tried to delete the versions of chromedriver, manually download and replace the executable, uninstal and reinstall webdrever-manager, and have tried different versions of webdriver-manager. Nothing has worked except for swtiching to other webdrivers like firefox or remote-chrome, but both of those have conflicts with other libraries we use so they aren't options. Any help would be must appreciated.

Comment: pls add the code you have for launching chrome driver / code to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

The `unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist` usually appears if there's a permissions issue. Some Python Selenium frameworks have default settings which prevent those issues from happening in the first place. There's one, [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), which not only sets optimal command-line options, but also includes a driver manager to make sure that your driver versions match your browser versions.

`pip install seleniumbase`, and then run with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
driver.get("https://seleniumbase.github.io/")
driver.quit()
```

You can find more options for that here: [seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py)

There's also a context manager format:

```py
from seleniumbase import DriverContext

with DriverContext(browser="chrome", headless=False) as driver:
    driver.get("https://seleniumbase.github.io/")
```

For other ways of structuring your tests, see [help_docs/syntax_formats](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md).